# How can I identify the FAF on this Jeppesen chart?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, aeronautical-charts, jeppesen

According to this Jeppesen ILS Approach Chart:

[image: ILS]

**How can the FAF be identified?**

Would it be the point at which the G/S is intercepted?

What is the difference between FAF and FAP?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where does the final approach segment begin on an ILS approach?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/25587/where-does-the-final-approach-segment-begin-on-an-ils-approach)

Comment: The proposed duplicate question is generic, this one is specific to one chart. The other answers point to the lightning and Maltese cross symbols, this chart doesn't show these symbols. Therefore it is not a duplicate in my eyes.

Answer (score 5):

The terminology is different between ICAO and the US.
The following definitions are being used by Jeppesen ([Introduction to Jeppesen Navigation Charts](https://ww1.jeppesen.com/documents/aviation/business/ifr-paper-services/glossary-legends.pdf)):

> **FINAL APPROACH FIX (FAF) —** The fix from
>   which the final approach (IFR) to an airport is executed and which identifies the beginning of the final
>   approach segment. It is designated in the profile
>   view of Jeppesen Terminal charts by the Maltese
>   Cross symbol for non-precision approaches and
>   by the glide slope/path intercept point on precision
>   approaches. The glide slope/path symbol starts at
>   the FAF. When ATC directs a lower-than-published
>   Glide Slope/Path Intercept Altitude, it is the resultant
>   actual point of the glide slope/path intercept.
>
> **FINAL APPROACH FIX (FAF) OR POINT (FAP)
>   (ICAO) —** That fix or point of an instrument approach
>   procedure where the final approach segment commences.
>
> **FINAL APPROACH POINT (FAP) (USA) —** The
>   point, applicable only to a non-precision approach
>   with no depicted FAF (such as an on-airport VOR),
>   where the aircraft is established inbound on the final
>   approach course from the procedure turn and where
>   the final approach descent may be commenced. The
>   FAP serves as the FAF and identifies the beginning
>   of the final approach segment.

So the FAF looks like this for non-precision approaches:

[image: FAF]

And for an ILS approach the FAP is number **8** in the following image:

[image: ILS]

Answer (score -1):

No. You intercept the GS long before FAP.

The FAF/FAP mark the beginning of the last segment. FAF is used for non-precision (non-glideslope) approaches, and FAP for ILS approaches.

The FAP is usually indicated by a Maltese Cross symbol. In the absence of that, the best clue that a fix on an ILS is the FAP is the GS crossing altitude indication.

[image]